# How to speed up loading/setting tile - OSMDROID

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am creating and setting a new tiles starting from a grib data, but the application is very slow:

```
try {
            gribFileTileSource.setRecord(1);
            for (int j=0;j<tileSize;j++) {
                lat=minLat+j*dLat;
                for (int i=0;i<tileSize;i++) {
                    lon=minLon+i*dLon;
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG,"lon:"+lon+" lat:"+lat);
                    u=gribFileTileSource.getValue(lat,lon);
                    color=gribFileTileSource.getColor(u);
                    bitmap.setPixel(i,tileSize-j-1,color);
                }
            }
```

How to make this code faster ?

Comment: if your tile provider uses the tilewriter, it can store your tiles in the osmdroid tile cache, which should speed it up significantly

Comment: Normal optimising procedure is to profile and find out where the time is spent and go from there.  I don't know what your grib structure is but a good bet all the time is in the getValue(lat,lon)  What are you getting back for u each call?

Comment: can you fetch an entire row of the grib file in one go, or at least the value and color?

Comment: for each call of getValue(lat,lon), i'm getting back the indices of the map tile [minLon - minLat] [maxLon - maxLat]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a custom tile source and are rendering stuff on the fly. If this is the case, you'll want to take a look at the MapsForge provider that was adapted for osmdroid.

The secret sauce that will help is in the following class:
 [MapsForgeTileModuleProvider](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-mapsforge/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/mapsforge/MapsForgeTileModuleProvider.java#L109)

This class performs a similar function, it render's tiles on the fly. After tiles are rendered, they are written to the `IFileSystemCache` which can be orders of magnitude faster via SQL than rendering/producing the image every time.

So basically, after you've produced the tile in question, store it in the `IFileSystemCache#.saveFile(tileSource, pTile, new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata));` or something to that effect (be sure to close the stream)

After you have the ability to generate your tiles, wire everything together with a class that extends `MapTileProviderArray`. Here's the example for the forge stuff:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-mapsforge/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/mapsforge/MapsForgeTileProvider.java

Note that it creates a [MapTileFilesystemProvider](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/modules/MapTileFilesystemProvider.java), which loads cached tile first, then the tile writer, then the tile provider (which generates tiles on the fly). This Custom Map Tile Provider Array can then be attached to the map using mapView.setTileProvider()

So this won't make tile rendering faster (well, it may since the module supports multiple threads, see [this](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-mapsforge/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/mapsforge/MapsForgeTileModuleProvider.java#L41)) but the biggest performance impact is storing the rendered tiles in the file system cache.

Comment: that's right, i'm producing a custom tile source on the fly. But in very slow. Now i'll try.

Comment: the main class I have to follow is `private class TileLoader extends MapTileModuleProviderBase.TileLoader` ?

Comment: @PasqualeCelardo just updated the answer with more detail

Comment: knowing the bounding-box of the tile is it possible to accelerate it all? is it possible to check if blocks of the tile are present in a cell of the grib? In such a way that instead of coloring 256x256 pixels, it is necessary to color only nRows x nCols of the cell of the grib